# How to split video to 3 parts by ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I want to split video to 3 parts in batch mode. So, I have this code:

```
@echo off
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_1.mp4
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_2.mp4
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:10 D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_3.mp4
pause
```

It works but having some problem:
1. It save file: .mp4_1.mp4. How to remove ".mp4" ?
2. When filename of video contain space character. It shows error: "Invalid argument". How to fix it ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ( 
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 "D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_1.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_2.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~nxi_3.mp4"
  )
pause
```

Comment: Hi, your code can split video which contain space character but it still show <filename>.mp4_1.mp4. Thanks !